# android: how to detect if incoming call activity is active

Tags: android, service

i build up app in android using service. In service i try to always show and hide(active and not) `myActivity` using Thread. So, if my activity is active, when user try to open another application my activity is always show because i check it every 1 second using Thread. But i have a problem, when incoming calls coming to my device my activity is always show, and it hide phone/call activity. I want to ask, how to detect phone/call activity, so if incoming activity or outgoing is active, my service will stop, and if it's finish(not active) my service will start again??

Comment: Can you please add more clarity to your question. Are you saying you want to detect if the call is inprogress?

Comment: No, i want to detect (when you get incoming calls in your device android). Because my activity id always show, so user can't open another app. But i want to make except if have incoming calls. Because if i get incoming calls, it's always hide, and my activity always show . .

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to detect an incoming call, then this will work. Also call register receiver in your service so that when your service is started the broadcastreceiver also starts.

```
public class CallReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver  {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

// Get the current Phone State
String phoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

if(phoneState == null)
   return;

// If phone is "Rininging"
if(phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
 {
   //phone is ringing, add what you want to happen here when incoming call comes
 }
}
```

In your manifest file,

```
    <!-- Register your Broadcast receiver  -->
    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" android:enabled="true"> 
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" /> 
            </intent-filter>
       </receiver>

</application>
```